# Must declare the scalar variable "@fecha"

Tags: sql-server

i need to generate a report and i have this in stored procedure

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[reproted]

@fecha date = null

as
begin

select tbldatostempcaptura2.iddatostempcaptura,tbldatostempcaptura2.primernombre, tbldatostempcaptura2.segundonombre,
tbldatostempcaptura2.primerapellido, tbldatostempcaptura2.segundoapellido, tbldatostempcaptura2.comentario,
tbldatostempcaptura2.fecharegistro, tbdatosgeneralesciudadano.fechanacimiento, tbdatosgeneralesciudadano.telefono, tbusuarios.idusuario
from tbldatostempcaptura2 inner join tbdatosgeneralesciudadano on tbldatostempcaptura2.iddatostempcaptura=tbdatosgeneralesciudadano.iddatostempcaptura
inner join tbusuarios on tbldatostempcaptura2.idusuario=tbusuarios.idusuario where tbldatostempcaptura2.fecharegistro=@fecha
end
```

any suggestions on how to declare @fecha?

Comment: Google *declare variable sql server*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
--drop proc [reproted]
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[reproted](@fecha SMALLDATETIME)
AS 

BEGIN
    SELECT 
        tbldatostempcaptura2.iddatostempcaptura,
        tbldatostempcaptura2.primernombre, 
        tbldatostempcaptura2.segundonombre, 
        tbldatostempcaptura2.primerapellido, 
        tbldatostempcaptura2.segundoapellido, 
        tbldatostempcaptura2.comentario, 
        tbldatostempcaptura2.fecharegistro, 
        tbdatosgeneralesciudadano.fechanacimiento, 
        tbdatosgeneralesciudadano.telefono, 
        tbusuarios.idusuario 
    FROM 
        tbldatostempcaptura2 
    INNER JOIN 
        tbdatosgeneralesciudadano 
    ON 
        tbldatostempcaptura2.iddatostempcaptura=tbdatosgeneralesciudadano.iddatostempcaptura 
    INNER JOIN 
        tbusuarios 
    ON 
        tbldatostempcaptura2.idusuario=tbusuarios.idusuario 
    WHERE 
        tbldatostempcaptura2.fecharegistro=@fecha 
END

GO
--exec reproted '2016/08/19'
```